# Using the with statement in Python 2.5: SyntaxError?

Tags: python, syntax, with-statement

I have the following python code, its working fine with python 2.7, but I want to run it on python 2.5.

I am new to Python, I tried to change the script multiple times, but i always I got syntax error. The code below throws a `SyntaxError: Invalid syntax`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import re
file = sys.argv[1]
exp = sys.argv[2]

print file
print exp
with open (file, "r") as myfile:

    data=myfile.read()

    p = re.compile(exp)
    matches = p.findall(data)
    for match in matches:
        print " ".join("{0:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in match)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 2.5 does not have the `with` code block support.

Do this instead:

```
myfile = open(file, "r")
try:
    data = myfile.read()
    p = re.compile(exp)
    matches = p.findall(data)
    for match in matches:
        print " ".join("{0:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in match)
finally:
    myfile.close()
```

**note:** you should not use `file` as the name of your file, it is an internal Python name, and it shadows the built in.

Answer (score 21):

Python 2.5 doesn't support the `with` statement yet.

To use it in Python 2.5, you'll have to import it from `__future__`:

```
## This shall be at the very top of your script ##
from __future__ import with_statement
```

Or, as in the previous versions, you can do the procedure manually:

```
myfile = open(file)
try:
    data = myfile.read()
    #some other things
finally:
    myfile.close()
```

Hope it helps!